# How to define hardcoded array data as part of a PHP framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

For example the 50 united states. Right now I use the 50 states in only a single function:

```
function getStateInput() {
    $states = array('AL' => 'Alabama', 'AK' => 'Alaska',
        'AZ' => 'Arizona', etc);

    //use $states
}
```

Alternatively you could define `$states` in its own states.php and then use it like this:

```
function getStateInput() {
    include('states.php');

    //use $states
}
```

But for some reason that scares me because I am using an include to define a local function variable. Another way would be to assign a states array to a superglobal in a states.php (for example I could use `$_ENV['states']`). Then I could go:

```
include('states.php');

function getStateInput() {
    //use $_ENV['states']
}
```

Is one of those best or is there another better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way is to separate concerns. You can eg. have your own class with address-related methods. This class would be the natural place to store information about possible states, like that:

```
class Address {
    static STATES = array(
        'AL' => 'Alabama',
        'AK' => 'Alaska',
        'AZ' => 'Arizona',
        // ...
    );
}

// and then you can use it somewhere like that:
echo Address::$STATES['AL'];
```

Comment: I prefer using static methods to global variables. Global array is soo  1990's

Comment: this is good. the only problems I see are that you have to come up with an additional name for the containing class and you also now have to decide if any other data might fit in that class.

Comment: @Ryan - Is that really a problem? Your entire application should be OOP these days, if your still using procedural programming you need to re-think your application design.

Comment: it's not a big deal. but i disagree that everything should be OOP. if all i need is a function then i'm just going to use a function. no sense in wrapping the function in a class(it's way more code to implement and use)

Comment: This is just a fake global variable. And it has even more overhead. If using this you should at least namespace the class. Like `class Myframework\States`

Comment: @localhost: It is not global array, nor a static method. One of the reasons I used that solution is that it does not pollute the global namespace (assuming some other features will be added to `Address` class). Also the class is not namespaces so it can work in PHP < 5.3 (which should be a standard on your hosting by now).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have the include file have a function that returns the state array. Then you use that array in your other code. That way you don't deal with any scope variables.

```
// states.php
function getStates() {
    return $states;
}

// other.php
function getStateInput() {
     include('states.php');   
     $states = getStates();
     // Do stuff with $states
}
```

Comment: i like this idea, but i would include states.php outside getStateInput() since all functions are global regardless of where you define them

Comment: A static class member would be much better then this as it will be created on initialization of the program, and not each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

In your `include.php` file (you have to include this file. Include it *before* your function declaration):

```
$states = array('GA' => 'Georgia', 'SC' => 'South Carolina');
```

On your script:

```
include("include.php");
global $states;

function GetStateInput() {
   ///States are already available as $states
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: use of globals is bad practice and is not recommended as it can cause un-expected problems if you re-use the variable elsewhere to store something else by accident. Use static class members instead as this will keep it inside the class but still be globally accessible.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `global` in your PHP code unless you absolutely can not avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this

**include.php**

```
<?php
$array = array();

$array['foo'] = 'bar';
$array['oof'] = 'rab';
... etc.

return $array;
?>
```

***framework***.php

```
<?php
// previous stuff

function getStateInput()
{
    static $a = NULL;
    if($a === NULL)
        $a = include('include.php');
    // do whatever
    return $a;
}

// other stuff
?>
```

Either that, or just define the array in the function. It would depend on how big the array is and how big the rest of the api. If maintenance gets a lot easier moving the array into an external file - do it. If you use the array in multiple different functions or methods, pull it out. etc. You know the drill.

PHP optimizes file includes, so don't worry about performance too much if you don't include dynamically.

Comment: I think it's cleaner to use a static array on a class because then you don't have to declare a variable in order to use it.

Comment: @Ryan you do realize that localhost 's comment was sarcasm? In fact using the code above will NOT clutter your global namespace as the $array variable will be local to the function it is defined in (the include is in the function thus the $array is local to the function). And using the return statement you don't need to know any variable names in the included file.